# useEffect with async and multiple set states doesn't seems to be batching

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im currently following a react course and got stuck with this question, in this code snippet im trying to fetch repositories using github API and while data is in process I used a state `isLoading` which has an initial value of `false`, and inside the `async` function this state will be toggled to `true` and then to `false` after the request is done, and im wondering why the "Loading..." text appears since react batches all updates until the end, why and how the JSX get access to the true value of the isLoading state? And thanks!

This is the component im using

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7/babel.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;

function App() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchRepos() {
            setIsLoading(true);

            const reposFetch = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users/OthmaneNissoukin/repos");
            const data = await reposFetch.json();

            setIsLoading(false);
        }
        fetchRepos();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
            {isLoading ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <div>Done!</div>}
        </div>
    );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I found that react does run the `setStates` update functions inside a batch that runs synchronously which will handle all the changes for updating and perform only one re-render in case if the setState is being performed in a synchronous function (like an event handler).

For example:

```
function App() {
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    // batch starts
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);  // schedule render
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1); // schedule render
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1): // schedule render
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1); // schedule render
    // Run scheduled render and update to 4
}, []);

return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h3>Counter: {counter}</h3>
    </div>
);
```

}

However, when trying to update the states inside an `async` function then the changes will be handled outside the batch which will lead to re-render for every useState update inside the async function.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    // batch already finished
    setTimeout(() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1), 1000);  // re-render 
    setTimeout(() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1), 2000); // re-render
    setTimeout(() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1), 3000): // re-render
    setTimeout(() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1), 4000); // re-render
    // This will render counter in an increment way since `setTimeOut()` is an async function.
}, []);
```

For more details, I recommend checking this article: https://dev.to/adamklein/we-don-t-know-how-react-state-hook-works-1lp8

And so in my question, the reason why "Loading..." appeared when the `fetch` has started was due to the `async` function that prevented the updates from batching all changes until the end and instead caused multiple re-renders whenever `isLoading` state was changed.

Answer (score 0):

since you dont have the data initially you need to make the default value of is loading to be true in the first render Loading will be displayed , in the second render toggled by the useEffect you fetch the data , set the data to the result of your fetch request and then change the state of loading .
your code should look like this :

```
function App() {
/* initial state of loading should be true since you have no data yet */
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
const [repos, setRepos] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchRepos() {
        

        const reposFetch = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users/OthmaneNissoukin/repos");
        const data = await reposFetch.json();
        /* set the the repo to the result of fetch */
        setRepos(data)
        /* change the state of loading so the data is shown */
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
    fetchRepos();
}, []);

return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        {isLoading ? <h2>Loading...</h2> : <div>{JSON.stringify(repos)}</div>}
    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the help! I couldnt understand the behaviour of those multiple `setIsLoading()` because I was thinking that react mechanism will not allow the `JSX` to access the truthy value.

Comment: setting is loading to true is standard , you can use it to show the loading screen while you fetch data or check authentication of user in the meanwhile . i'm glad this helped you .